# PHP Multiple File Uploading

Tags: php, file-upload

HTML for the file uplods:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
                <br/>Upload Featured Image: <input name="imagefiles" type="file" /><br/>
                <br/>Upload Gallery Image 1: <input name="imagefiles" type="file" /><br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Product" />

</form>
```

To handle the upload, I'm doing this:

```
$imagefiles = $_FILES['imagefiles'];
               foreach ($imagefiles['name'] as $key => $value) ----> [Line 25 in file]
                {


                }
```

But, I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/addProductForm.php on line 25 (Edit)
```

Comment: I assume that "----> [Line 25 in file]" is not part of the code?

Comment: @Brendon Cheves, ya, u right!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not using correct parameter names.
You have to add `[]` to make your input an array, otherwise the last element will override previous elements with same name..

Try HTML below:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
   <br/>Upload Featured Image: <input name="imagefiles[]" type="file" /><br/>
   <br/>Upload Gallery Image 1: <input name="imagefiles[]" type="file" /><br/>
   <br/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Product" />
</form>
```